# Find the minimum digit of a NaturalNumber n

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to find the minimum digit of a natural number when I call this method.  I must use recursion.  Where am I going wrong? (I'd like to use my general code structure as well)

```
private static int minDigit(NaturalNumber n) {
    int min = 9;
    if (!n.isZero()) {
        int k = n.divideBy10();
        k = minDigit(n);
        if (k < min) {
            min = k;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: What do you see and what did you expect to see?  Do you understand why the program generate what you see?

Answer (score 0):

In order for recursion to work, the recursive call needs to be made on a smaller version of the problem, so that eventually it gets so small that the answer is obvious.  But your code makes the recursive call on the same number, `n`, it was called with, and thus never makes any progress to that state.

Further, if `n` *is* zero, then shouldn't the minimum digit *be* 0?  If `n` can never be 0, why do you need to test for it?

Comment: Nah, with NaturalNumbers, the function n.divideBy10(); takes off the last digit of n, so n is smaller